# Flip and Mirror numbers

Tags: swift, algorithm, data-structures

I have just picked up an interview question from the Internet and practicing with Swift.

Question is as follows:

**Given an input of an array of string, verify if, turned 180 degrees, it is the "same".**

**For instance:**

```
[1, 6, 0, 9, 1] => return true 
[1, 7, 1] => return false
```

I have come up with the following approach which I put mirroring numbers in the dictionary and check whether or not if any number in the given array do not match with dictionary numbers.

It seems it works with basic test cases, but I wonder if I am missing anything ?

```
func checkRotation (nums : [Int]) -> Bool
{
    var dict = [Int : Int]()
    dict  = [0:0, 1:1, 2:5, 5:2, 6:9, 8:8, 9:6]

    for n in nums
    {
        guard let exist = dict[n] else
        {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: This belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @RobNapier, this question is being asked by Facebook and Google. I even remember that this question was being asked before by one of the company that I had interview before.

Comment: `[1, 0, 9, 1]` shouldn't work. if "exist", check the value of "n" at nums[n-indexOfIt].

Comment: Yeah; Facebook and Google are pretty notorious about horrible interview questions.

Comment: @Larme, it is really good catch!

Comment: Also you only need to go until the half size of the array + "center" (if count is even).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
extension Collection where Element == Int {
    func isFlipMirrored() -> Bool {
        let mirrors = [0:0, 1:1, 6:9, 8:8, 9:6]
        return zip(self, self.reversed()) // Create tuples of each element and its opposite
            .allSatisfy {                 // Return whether all of them match the rule:
                mirrors[$0] == $1         // That the element matches its opposite's mirror
        }
    }
}
```

This isn't as efficient as it could be, but it's very simple and to the point. It just verifies that each element of the sequence is the same as the mirrored elements in the reverse order.

It could be more efficient to only check the first half of the elements, but it's a pretty minor optimization that requires extra conditionals, so I'm not sure if it would really be faster for reasonably small N. You'd need to profile before complicating the code too much.

Of course, just because it's not actually slower (i.e. I haven't profiled it to know), that doesn't mean that an interviewer won't baulk at the fact that this code makes redundant checks. There are a lot of misunderstandings about performance, and they all seem to show up in interview questions. So, let's make the interviewer happy and only check the first half of the list against the last half.

```
extension Collection where Element == Int {
    func isFlipMirrored() -> Bool {
        let mirrors = [0:0, 1:1, 6:9, 8:8, 9:6]

        // May test one more thing than we technically have to, but fewer conditionals
        let midpoint = count / 2 + 1

        return zip(self.prefix(midpoint),             // Create tuples of the left-half of the list,
                   self.reversed().prefix(midpoint))  //    and the right half
            .allSatisfy {                 // Return whether all of them match the rule:
                mirrors[$0] == $1         //     that the element matches its opposite's mirror
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please add extra comment on `zip(self, self.reverse()).allsatisfy{}` line. It is high order method and very very compact and quite impressing!

Comment: Your `mirrors` is missing `2:5`.

Comment: If you rotate 2 180 degrees, you don't get 5. You get 5 if you flip it (in some fonts), but not if you rotate it. (In some fonts, 2 rotates to 2 and 5 rotates to 5.)

Comment: True, but then why do you have `5:2`?

Comment: fair; because I removed one and not the other :D

Comment: @hotspring You should break it down. Play around with `zip` first, see what it does, then play around with `allSatisfy`, and then see what happens when you combine the two together.

Comment: Thanks a lot Alexandar and @Rob Napier for the all the great comments and directions and knowledge that you shared with me. These are really helpful and hopefully others who will check this question will think the same. I had been thinking to use Python for an interview, but I see Swift is almost powerful as Python with all these high order functions.

Comment: It seems `allSatisfy` is supported Swift 4.2 onwards.

Comment: Yes, because `count / 2 + 1` is 2 (integer math), so it's going to check [1, 7] against [7, 1]. It will fail on the first test

Comment: "that an interviewer won't baulk at the fact that this code makes redundant checks" If I was the inverviewer, if he/she tells me that it might really depends on the size of the array because it adds checks, etc. should it be tested in production, I'd take that one rather than the one that simply say "yes", let's do that, without challenging the idea.

Comment: In my 30 years of professional programming, I've never passed a whiteboard interview, so you probably can't take my advice on these things. :D

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
func checkRotation (nums : [Int]) -> Bool
{
    var dict = [0:0, 1:1, 2:5, 5:2, 6:9, 8:8, 9:6]
    return nums.filter{ dict[$0] != nil }.count == nums.count

}
```

Or

```
func checkRotation (nums : [Int]) -> Bool
{
    var dict = [0:0, 1:1, 2:5, 5:2, 6:9, 8:8, 9:6]
    return nums.compactMap{ dict[$0]}.count == nums.count

}
```

Comment: could you please add a short explanation? It seems you are filtering numbers in the given array with a set of key(dict) and checking whether or not we have same input array length. why did you use compactMap operation?

Comment: Please check @Larme comments, it seems we both are missing the case. I have up-voted your effort.

Answer (score 1):

To know if array is convertible, you need to

- traverse items upto index `N/2` (including middle one for odd-length array)
- check whether all items belong to dictionary
- check that `dict[nums[i]] == nums[N-i-1]`

I don't know Swift, but Python example should look very close:

```
def isconv(lst):
    dict = {0:0, 1:1, 2:5, 5:2, 6:9, 8:8, 9:6}
    N = len(lst)
    for i in range((N + 1) // 2):
        if (lst[i] not in dict) or (dict[lst[i]] != lst[N - 1 - i]):
            return False
    return True

print(isconv([1,6,0,9,1]))
print(isconv([5,5,2,2]))
print(isconv([1,6,0,6,1]))
print(isconv([1,4,1]))
>>True
>>True
>>False
>>False
```

Comment: could you please add your solution here?

Comment: @hotspring Added working Python example to demonstrate  approach

Answer (score 1):

I have some issues with your code, which I've annotated below:

```
func checkRotation /* Why the space here? */ (nums /* Why the space here? */ : [Int]) -> Bool
{ // Brackets like this aren't Swift's code style
    // Dict is a horrible name. I can see that it's a dictionary. What is it a dict *of*?!
    var dict = [Int : Int]() // Why is this a `var` variable, that's assigned an empty initial value
    dict  = [0:0, 1:1, 2:5, 5:2, 6:9, 8:8, 9:6] // only to be immediately overwritten?

    for n in nums // This should be a `contains(_:)` call, rather than explicit enumeration
    {
        // If you're not using a `contains(_:)` check, you should at least use a `where` clause on the for loop
        guard let exist = dict[n] else // "exist" is a bad variable name, and it's not even used. Replace this with a `dict[n] != nil` check.
        {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Here is how I would write it in a *similar* way:

```
func checkRotation(nums: [Int]) -> Bool {
    let mirroredDigits = [0:0, 1:1, 2:5, 5:2, 6:9, 8:8, 9:6]

    for n in nums where mirroredDigits[n] == nil {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: Please check @Larme comments, it seems we both are missing the case. I have up-voted your effort. By the way, thanks a lot for commenting out on my code as well. it is really valuable.

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be to use `prefix` to limit the data set and `enumerated` to enumerate over indexes and values simultaneously.  Throw in `lazy` so you don't make lots of array copies and only process what's relevant.

```
extension Array where Element == Int {
    func isMirrored() -> Bool {
        let flipped = [0:0, 1:1, 2:5, 5:2, 6:9, 8:8, 9:6]

        return lazy                         // means we won't make 3 copies of arrays
            .prefix((count + 1) / 2)        // stops the enumeration at the midway point
            .enumerated()                   // enumerates over (index, value)
            .allSatisfy { (index, value) in // verify all elements meet the criteria below

            // make sure each reversed element matches it's flipped value
            // Note you don't have to explicitly check for nil, since
            // '==' works on Optional<Int>
                return flipped[value] == self[count - index - 1]
            }
    }
}

[1, 6, 0, 9, 1].isMirrored()
[1, 7, 1].isMirrored()
```